# get spin object value from Camunda history variable-instances Rest API

Tags: camunda, camunda-spin

I am using a serviceTask, to make a Rest API from camunda.

it has variables like URL, headers, payload, method and other things.

all these variables are Inline script varaibles.

for URL, headers, method we storing string values.

for payload we are storing spin object, since the value may cross 4000 characters. As camunda can't store a string more than 4000 characters we started using Spin object.

All working as expected.

For debugging purpose we wanted to see all the values of task variables. we are able to extract all the string variables but not spin object variable.

I am using Following API to get variable value.

http:///engine-rest/history/variable-instance/

I am getting following response.

```
{
    "type": "Json",
    "value": {
        "dataFormatName": "application/json",
        "boolean": false,
        "number": false,
        "string": false,
        "object": true,
        "nodeType": "OBJECT",
        "value": false,
        "array": false,
        "null": false
    },
    "valueInfo": {},
    "id": "b99aa041-0e8d-11ee-8d36-0242ac180016",
    "name": "payload",
    "processDefinitionKey": "<process definition key>",
    "processDefinitionId": "1b592498-d87a-11ed-bd53-0242ac180018",
    "processInstanceId": "af36683e-0e8d-11ee-8d36-0242ac180016",
    "executionId": "b9600836-0e8d-11ee-8d36-0242ac180016",
    "activityInstanceId": "ServiceTask_04gain0:b9600837-0e8d-11ee-8d36-0242ac180016",
    "caseDefinitionKey": null,
    "caseDefinitionId": null,
    "caseInstanceId": null,
    "caseExecutionId": null,
    "taskId": null,
    "errorMessage": null,
    "tenantId": null,
    "state": "CREATED",
    "createTime": "2023-06-19T10:40:36.216+0000",
    "removalTime": "2023-07-04T10:41:03.951+0000",
    "rootProcessInstanceId": "af36683e-0e8d-11ee-8d36-0242ac180016"
}
```

The above response not containing any value in it.
I am not sure how to extract the actual value.

Can someone help me here.